# How to save the chat historial of gradio.Chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, gradio

I have this data:

```
data = [
    {"human1": "i am human", "human2": None},
    {"human1": None, "human2": "i can help"},
    {"human1": None, "human2": "i can do many things"},
    {"human1": "give me an example", "human2": None}
]
with open('data.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)
```

That stores the chat history using gradio.Chatbot. this is the code:

```
def send_message(msg, history):
    time.sleep(1)

    data.append({"human1": msg, "human2": None})
    with open('data.yaml', 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(data, file)

    return "", history + [[msg, None]]

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with open('data.yaml', 'r') as file:
        data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    history = gr.Chatbot([(item.get("human1"), item.get("human2")) for item in data])
    msg = gr.Textbox()

    msg.submit(send_message, [msg, history], [msg, history])

demo.launch()
```

The problem is that everytime I open a new browser tab, the history disappears, however the file data.yaml is storing the conversations correctly.

Any idea?